# Created user in USVN but user cannot access the repository

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I've got a repository with many subdirectories and I created a user who has permission to access a specific directory.  I've checked the authz file on the server and doublechecked the permissions in the USVN control panel and the user still cannot access the directory.
If I navigate to the repository using a web browser, it asks for the username and password but doesn't accept the credentials.  The credentials work when logging into USVN and I'm able to navigate to the files using USVN but direct HTTP access and using TortoiseSVN doesn't work.
I'm using USVN 0.7.2

Comment: I'm not even sure that USVN is supported anymore. I'd suggest taking a closer look at other products that either come with built-in web interface for SVN repositories or other web interface components.

Comment: USVN 0.7.2 was released on 01 Nov 2008. Today is year 2016. :)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was an issue where the password in active directory didn't match the password in usvn.  I set the password in AD to match the one in usvn and it works now.